# Анимация linear-gradient нагрузка cpu

Tags: css, css-animation

У меня есть progress bar, нужно сделать его анимированным фоном, вот пример:

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4A90E2 0%, #9BFAC0 50%, #4A90E2 100%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  animation: progress 3s ease infinite;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    background-position: 200% 0%
  }
  99% {
    background-position: 0% 0%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

При такой анимации нагрузка на cpu в районе 10-30% от macbookpro без отдельной gpu.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с таким и как возможно реализовать такую анимацию без такой нагрузки?

Конечно я думал, что анимация background-position не лучший вариант, но абсолютно такое-же поведение даже со вставкой png картинки с анимацией на translateX (и с указанием will-change: transform)

Экспериментирую дальше, проблема производится даже без градиента, с максимально облегченным кодом и простой линейной анимацией:

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #4A90E2;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.progress-bar:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #9BFAC0;
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
  animation: progress 3s linear infinite;
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes progress {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-200%)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(200%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

**UPD**
Перепробовал почти все варианты и не нашел решения. Можно снизить нагрузку изменением анимации, делая ее с промежутками. Аналогичная нагрузка показывается и на toggle class + transition. SVG анимация – нагрузка в 1.5 раза больше. Все, что находится в гугле это will-change и null transform – не помогают. Остается gif? Но он ведь тоже будет перерисовываться, но ему можно задать скорость кадра.

Comment: А если цвета с прозрачностью то ещё хуже или так же?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал двигать объект внутри прогресбара с существующим градиентом

Comment: @RuslanSemenov – пробовал, об этом написал тоже. Stranger in the Q – примерно так-же

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: #4A90E2;
}

.progress-bar span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4A90E2, #9BFAC0 50%, #4A90E2);
  animation: progress 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    left: -200%
  }
  100% {
    left: 200%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня канеш не макбук, но ваш вариант в моём случай жрёт всего на 1% меньше

Comment: По хорошему, можно отказаться от transparent станет легче, нужно пробовать

Comment: @RuslanSemenov отказался даже от градиента, а улучшений особых нет ;(

Comment: Интересно, что у меня нагрузки нет, а другой браузер помимо сафари пробовали?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov я в хроме, у вас возможно видеокарта дискретная, у меня интегрированная.

Comment: У меня аналогично нет дискретной карты win10 и так же нагрузка как у ТС идёт на cpu правда в случае кода автора 8-12%, в данном случаей 8-11%